# How to rotate ImageView without loss of quailty in edges of image

Tags: java, android, image, graphics, android-canvas

[image]

```
I created two linearlayout with rotation and  then I placed the imageview in it ...
If the app loads and imageview displayed the edges of images in imageview look like this 
How can i get the imageview with proper edges.
```

Below is my xml content for this:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="220dp"
        android:background="@drawable/mainscreen_imageframe"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:rotation="-8" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgBride"
            android:layout_width="150dip"
            android:layout_height="132dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:background="@drawable/noimage" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-47dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="210dp"
        android:background="@drawable/mainscreen_imageframe"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:rotation="9" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgGroom"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="132dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/noimage" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Friends hep me to solve this ...
how to get proper image edges in rotation

Comment: How did you solved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your imageviews in your xml

```
android:antialias="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

try making it 9 patch image with 9 patch tool . It will make the image stretchable.

Comment: 9 patch tool is inside the android-sdk/tools folder